# Setting value of Entry using tkinter, MVC and Observables

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, model-view-controller, tkinter

I am trying to build a simple GUI using tkinter to read in CSV's and then run some text mining functions. I am having difficulty understand tkinter's callback function. The following code was created using this ToyMVC code.

I am able to get the GUI to pop up but am having trouble getting the rightmost Entry widget (variable name = finalPathEntry) to update with the user-inputted text from the left Widget once the user presses the button.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to move forward and what I am doing wrong.

Best,

```
import tkinter as tk

class Observable:
    def __init__(self, initialValue=None):
        self.data = initialValue
        self.callbacks = {}

def addCallback(self, func):
    self.callbacks[func] = 1

def delCallback(self, func):
    del self.callback[func]

def _docallbacks(self):
    for func in self.callbacks:
         func(self.data)

def set(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self._docallbacks()

def get(self):
    return self.data

def unset(self):
    self.data = None


class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.csvPath = Observable("")

    def addPath(self, value):
        self.csvPath.set(self.csvPath.get())


class View(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.master.destroy)
        tk.Label(self, text='Please input path to CSV').pack(side='left')

        self.pathEntry = tk.Entry(self, width=50)
        self.pathEntry.pack(side='left')
        self.addButton = tk.Button(self, text='Read CSV', width=8)
        self.addButton.pack(side='left')
        self.path = tk.StringVar()
        self.finalPathEntry = tk.Entry(self, width = 30, textvariable = self.path)
        self.finalPathEntry.pack(side='left')

    def setPath(self, value):
        self.path.set(str(value)) 


class Controller:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.model = Model()
        self.model.csvPath.addCallback(self.pathChanged)
        self.view1 = View(root)
        self.view1.minsize(width = 500, height = 500)
        self.view1.addButton.config(command=self.addPath)
        self.pathChanged(self.model.csvPath.get())

    def addPath(self):
        self.model.addPath(self.view1.pathEntry.get())

    def pathChanged(self, val):
        self.view1.setPath(val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    app = Controller(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: Using the answer below, I have fixed my code. Here is the updated and working snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Observable:
    def __init__(self, initialValue = None):
        self.data = initialValue
        self.callbacks = {}

    def addCallback(self, func):
        self.callbacks[func] = 1

    def delCallback(self, func):
        del self.callback[func]

    def _docallbacks(self):
        for func in self.callbacks:
            func(self.data)

    def set(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self._docallbacks()

    def get(self):
        return self.data

    def unset(self):
        self.data = None

class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.csvPath = Observable("")

    def addPath(self, value):
        self.csvPath.set(self.csvPath.get())

class View(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.master.destroy)
        tk.Label(self, text='Please input path to CSV').pack(side='left')
        self.pathEntry = tk.Entry(self, width=50)
        self.pathEntry.pack(side='left')
        self.addButton = tk.Button(self, text='Read CSV', width=8)
        self.addButton.pack(side='left')
        self.path = tk.StringVar()
        self.finalPathEntry = tk.Entry(self, width = 30, textvariable = self.path)
        self.finalPathEntry.pack(side='left')

    def setPath(self, value):
        self.path.set(str(value))

class Controller:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.model = Model()
        self.model.csvPath.addCallback(self.pathChanged)
        self.view1 = View(root)
        self.view1.minsize(width = 500, height = 500)
        self.view1.addButton.config(command = self.addPath)
        self.pathChanged(self.model.csvPath.get())

    def addPath(self):
        self.model.addPath(self.view1.pathEntry.get())

    def pathChanged(self, val):
        self.view1.setPath(val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    app = Controller(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to fix the indentation of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing about this code seems obvious: The functions beginning at

```
def addcallback(self, func):
```

until

```
def unset(self):
```

are not part of the Observable class. So the "self" argument is not what you expect it to be. You should indent these functions.